# How to preChache list of Svg Icons

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

```
class Images {

static const String MAIL_ICON = 'assets/svg/mail_icon.svg';

static const String LOCK_ICON = 'assets/svg/lock_icon.svg';
static const String MENU_ICON = 'assets/svg/menu.svg';
static const String EXIT_ICON = 'assets/svg/exit_icon.svg';
static const String CROSS_ICON = 'assets/svg/cross_icon.svg';

static final List<String> svgAssets = [
MAIL_ICON,
LOCK_ICON,
MENU_ICON,
EXIT_ICON,
CROSS_ICON,
];
}
```

I am using flutter_svg package but i think it doest support prechaching help me out with this